# How to concatenate Integers as Strings in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, integer, concatenation

I want to concatenate strings in Haskell and also integers
from function like this:

```
arc 13 34 234 3
```

13 34 234 3 will be arguments of arc function and I want output like

```
"arc(13, 34, 234, 3)"
```

as a String how can I implement this?

Comment: Are you sure that your `arc` function should have 4 `Int` arguments? Maybe [Int] will be more usable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `String` output, the typical technique is to create a `ShowS`, which is just another name for `String -> String`.

```
showsArc :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ShowS
showsArc a b c d = showString "arc" . shows (a, b, c, d)

>>> showsArc 13 34 234 3 []
"arc(13,34,234,3)"
```

The `[]` at the end of the function call is just an empty string.  It lets you attach data to the end without worrying about `O(N)` string concatenation.

```
>>> showsArc 13 34 234 3 " and some extra text"
"arc(13,34,234,3) and some extra text"
```

Comment: i tried this but ghci gives ˙Arc.hs:30:1:
    Invalid type signature: Arc :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ShowS
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
˙

Comment: You can't name a function (or value) starting with a capital letter: `Arc` is an invalid function name in Haskell.  (Only constructors, types, modules, and classes are named starting with capital letters.)

Answer (score 9):

How can list of numbers could be concatenated into a string? Looks like some `[Int] -> String` function can help here.

```
> concat . intersperse ", " . map show $ [13, 34, 234, 3]
"13, 34, 234, 3"
```

So, let's add some brackets and "arc" to that String.

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

arc :: [Int] -> String
arc nums = "arc(" ++ (concat . intersperse ", " . map show $ nums) ++ ")"
```

And we get the answer.

```
> arc  [13, 34, 234, 3]
"arc(13, 34, 234, 3)"
```

If you are really need function with signature like `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String`:

```
arc' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
arc' a1 a2 a3 a4 = "arc(" ++ (concat . intersperse ", " . map show $ [a1,a2,a3,a4]) ++ ")"

> arc' 13 34 234 3
"arc(13, 34, 234, 3)"
```